# combining dimple.js with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I want to add zooming functionality using d3.js in a bar chart created using dimple.js. See following link for what I did so far. http://jsbin.com/rejof/2/edit
I want to combine both zooming functionality in dimple chart. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do this, you would probably need to modify the dimple source code as I believe zooming relies on a different dom structure to the one dimple uses.  You might find it easier to recreate the chart you require in raw d3, rather than modifying a dimple chart to zoom.  Of course I'd love to be proven wrong.